# Is there any resource to learn how drupal 8 configurations work?

Tags: drupal, configuration, drupal-8

I'm confused to know how to drupal 8 configurations work,if there any resources please list them.

Answer (score 1):

Managing your site's configuration
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management/managing-your-sites-configuration

Defining and using your own configuration in Drupal 8
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/defining-and-using-your-own-configuration-in-drupal-8

Your Complete Introduction to Drupal 8 Configuration Management
https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/config/

Answer (score 0):

Good book: Drupal 8 Configuration Management ISBN-10: 1783985208 ISBN-13: 978-1783985203

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Drupal-Configuration-Management-Stefan-Borchert/dp/1783985208/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1477733283&sr=8-1&keywords=drupal+8+configuration+management